# Symmetric PDFs for random sets

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, symmetric-functions

I’m studying the probability theory for finite sets (in my field we call them *Random Finite Sets*, but they are known as *(simple) Point Processes*).
In this context, a random finite set is a random variable whose values are finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Let’s say that a random finite set is composed by two random points $x_1$, $x_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Since sets are not ordered, the joint PDF $f(x_1,x_2)$ of $x_1$, $x_2$ must be symmetric, in the sense that
$$f(x_1,x_2)=f(x_2,x_1)$$
must hold.
Let’s suppose that $\tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)$ is a non-symmetric PDF, then we can define its symmetrization as
$$f(x_1,x_2)\triangleq \frac{\tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)+\tilde{f}(x_2,x_1)}{2}.$$
This is the proposed solution by the theory.

Moreover, the theory explicitly forbids sets containing repeated elements, in the sense that it must satisfy $f(x_1,x_1)=0$ and $f(x_2,x_2)=0$.

**Question**

**(1)** In my opinion we can achieve symmetry even by considering the transformation
$$f(x_1,x_2) = \tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)\tilde{f}(x_2,x_1).$$
Why don’t we do it that way? What are the disadvantages of this strategy?

Comment: Do you need $\iint  f(x_1,x_2) =1$?

Comment: yes, $f(x_1,x_2)$ has to be a PDF, so it must integrate to the unity

Comment: The proposed solution has this property provided that $\tilde  f(x_1,x_2)$ does.  In general, your suggested alternative would usually not have this property.  You could try $f(x_1,x_2) = \dfrac{\tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)\tilde{f}(x_2,x_1)}{\iint \tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)\tilde{f}(x_2,x_1)}$ so long as the denominator is finite and positive; this is similar to the proposed solution being $ \dfrac{\tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)+\tilde{f}(x_2,x_1)}{\iint (\tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)+\tilde{f}(x_2,x_1))}$ where the denominator is clearly $2$.

Comment: yes, I forgot the normalizing factor. However, thinking about it, it seems easier to consider arithmetic averages rather than products. Even from a numerical point of view, it seems more convenient to avoid my solution.

Answer (score 2):

*From comments:*

In general, your suggested alternative would usually not have the property $\iint  f(x_1,x_2) =1$ needed to be a probability density.  The proposed solution has this property provided that $\tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)$ does.

You could try $f(x_1,x_2) = \dfrac{\tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)\tilde{f}(x_2,x_1)}{\iint \tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)\tilde{f}(x_2,x_1)}$ so long as the denominator is finite and positive,

which is similar to the proposed solution being $ \frac{\tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)+\tilde{f}(x_2,x_1)}{\iint (\tilde{f}(x_1,x_2)+\tilde{f}(x_2,x_1))}$ where the denominator is clearly $2$.